# How to reference only ids with a many to many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this aggregate root

```
CustomerGroup
int Id
string Name
Customer[] Customers
```

And this one

```
Customer
int Id
string Name
```

My model was built using EF 4. What i'd prefer would be (for sticking to the concept of aggregate root)

```
CustomerGroup
int Id
string Name
int[] Customers
```

How would you do this ?

A customer might be in many gorup (many to many relationship) but I only need the relationship in one way group -> customer. I don't have any use case where I need customer -> group.

Comment: Some questions: why should `CustomerGroup` be an aggregate root? Could it not be part of the `Customer` aggregate? And would you ever need the array of customer id's _only_? Wouldn't it only be addressed to find customers, so why not use a `Customers` collection right away?

Comment: Because in my software we need to be able to sell a service to a CustomerGroup (if the group change then the product will be available only for customers in this group). There is a GUI for editing a group and many gui where we only use the notion of group without customer so I'm sure it's an aggregate root.

Comment: This only confirms that `Customer` and `CustomerGroup` are closely aggregated. I mean: there is no `CustomerGroup` without a `Customer` and vice versa. I think it's arbitrary which one is the aggregate root. But is this such a consequential decision? Maybe you should expand on that a bit. I sense that we're not discussing the heart of the matter.

Comment: You can have a CustomerGroup without a customer like you can have a class without student ! A Customer is not defined by its groups that's why there is no reference of the groups inside of it and a customer might not be in any gorups at all. And I can sell a service only to an alone customer, so they are both aggregates !

Comment: OK with me, but why does it matter so much? If you have a `CustomerGroup` with a `Customers` collection it's up to you whether or not you query it. You can also map the junction table explicitly and let `CustomerGroup` have a collection of the lightweight `CustomerGroupCustomer` junction records.

Comment: How do I do this "lightweight junction records" or I "map the junction table explicitly" ? My association is a many to many relation, so I don't want to load all my customer's data only for knowing if 1 customer id is in a specific group.

Comment: Please see my answer. Too much for a comment :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a many-to-many association between `Customer` and `CustomerGroup` there also is a so called junction table, let's say `CustomerGroupCustomer`, that has `CustomerId` and `CustomerGroupId`.

If this table only has these two fields EF can use it implicitly, which means that `CustomerGroup` can have a `Customers` collection where in the mapping you indicate that `CustomerGroupCustomer` is the junction table. [Here](http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/15/entity-framework-4-1-many-to-many-relationships-5/) is an example. You can, but don't have to, map `Customer.CustomerGroups`. When working database-first, this implicit behaviour is the default.

However, since you're interested in `CustomerId`s only you could decide to have a regular one-to-many association `CustomerGroup.CustomerGroupCustomers`. If you address this navigation property only one join is required and the query is pretty light. If you have a `CustomerGroup` instance you can do

```
group.CustomerGroupCustomers.Select(c => c.CustomerId)
```

and only the `CustomerId`s will be queried.

If you want you can get the `Customers` directly by doing

```
group.CustomerGroupCustomers.Select(c => c.Customer)
```

Comment: Here if I create a CustomerGroupCustomers, I have to initialize its foreign key "GroupId" or there is a way of saying "you take this id from the group you are in".

Comment: Yes, just add a CustomerGroupCustomers object to the collection in CustomerGroup. EF will manage the Id's.

Comment: Yes but I'll have to initialize CustomerGroupCustomers.Group right ?

Comment: That's right. Set it's CustomerId or Customer object and add it to the group's collection.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just created a new property that did that?  You could extend the partial if you're using an edmx, or create a non-mapped if using code first.

```
public class CustomerGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NAme { get; set; }
    public Customer[] Customers { get; set; }

    public int[] CustomerIds { get { return Customers.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray(); }
}
```

Comment: I'm using an edmx. But your solution means that it'd load all the customers informations when I just need the ids !

Comment: you can use this using an edmx by adding as a partial.  You're correct in that it would load all the customer information, but don't you need that anyway? If the Customers are included when you load the customer group, the customers are already stored in memory and there won't be an additional sql call to gather the data.  Are your customer objects extremely large so you're trying to avoid loading them at all?

Comment: Customers <-> Group i a many to many relationship, so I need only the customers Id, not the name or something else.